# How to download a file in ASP.NET MVC using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm working on an assignment, and I'm stuck in downloading section. I can upload the file. But when I'm trying to download the same file after uploading, I get an error ("Access is denied").

Here is the code which I have written:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult Download (string fileName)
{
    var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);

    var writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, @"D:\Assignment\Ment\Ment\Photos");
    permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);

    var FileVirtualPath = Server.MapPath("~/Photos/" + fileName); //"~/Photos/" + fileName;

    return new FilePathResult(@"D:\Assignment\Ment\Ment\Photos", "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Comment: You use MapPath and then don’t use that for actually returning a file, rather suddenly return a result to a folder. Create permissionSet and don’t use it for anything.

Comment: Can you edit this code?

Comment: I Changed the code to this, But still not working                                                                                                                           
   var FileVirtualPath = ("~/Photos/" + fileName);
            return File(FileVirtualPath,"application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
[HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        //fileName should be like "photo.jpg"
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos"),fileName);
        return File(fullPath, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
    }
```

Comment: I changed the code to this, And now i am getting error .............  Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Work\Ment\Ment\Photos\photo.jpg'.

Comment: I tried adding this code in my controller in asp net core mvc project but cant figure out which import I need for Server

Comment: @SteveW should be under System.Web, make sure you reference it in your project

Comment: I tried adding using System.Web but it doesn't work. I am trying to do this inside my MVC controller action method. Does this make a difference? I will make a new question and give you the link if you don't mind helping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874934/actionlink-and-method-to-download-file-from-asp-net-mvc-project

Comment: sorry, didnt realize you were using .net core

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that :

```
public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
{
    return File(“<your path>” + ImageName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

Also, visit this links :

[ASP.NET MVC Uploading and Downloading Files](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/125/asp-net-mvc-uploading-and-downloading-files)

[Upload and download files using ASP.NET MVC](http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp-net-mvc/)